# How do I get the permalink of a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I can get the permalink of a specific post tag or category, but what if I want to get the permalink of a custom post type? I can't find anything in the Codex or anywhere else about how to do this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How about `href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ); ?>"`, where `$post_type` is your post type?

Further reading: [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_archive_link/)

Comment: Small improvement; <?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( $post->post_type ); ?>

Using $post->post_type instead of $post_type gives the slug directly.

Answer (score 8):

Within the loop, you can simply use [`the_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink). Outside of the loop, you can use [`get_permalink( $id )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink).

Comment: That returns the permalink of a specific post or page. I want to return the permalink of a post type. So, for instance, if there is a post type called "movie reviews", and the permalink of that post type is "www.website.com/movie-reviews", how do I get that permalink? Maybe this is not a true permalink technically, I just want the URL of that post type.

Answer (score 1):

Or, for what it's worth, `get_term_link($term, $taxonomy);` - [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link).

Answer (score 1):

I know this post might be old but just in case someone else is searching the function that does this, here's the one i wrote.  $post_type must be passed as a variable :)

```
if( !function_exists( 'wp_get_post_type_link' )  ){
    function wp_get_post_type_link( &$post_type ){

        global $wp_rewrite; 

        if ( ! $post_type_obj = get_post_type_object( $post_type ) )
            return false;

        if ( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) && is_array( $post_type_obj->rewrite ) ) {

            $struct = $post_type_obj->rewrite['slug'] ;
            if ( $post_type_obj->rewrite['with_front'] )
                $struct = $wp_rewrite->front . $struct;
            else
                $struct = $wp_rewrite->root . $struct;

            $link = home_url( user_trailingslashit( $struct, 'post_type_archive' ) );       

        } else {
            $link = home_url( '?post_type=' . $post_type );
        }

        return apply_filters( 'the_permalink', $link );
    }
}
```

Hope it helps ! :)

Answer (score 0):

@Stefan KRUGER

curious why the value is passed by reference:
&$post_type

aside: I dont' understand why i can supply an answer, which is not what this is, but NOT a comment, which is what this is. that seems backward.